# Android: Where does the "System tools" permission come from?

Tags: android, xml, permissions, google-play, manifest

I've got an Android App on Google Play and when installing it, it says it has the Persmission "System Tools - test access to protected storage. Allows the app to test a permission for USB storage that will be availavle on future devices".

I don't really understand that permission and I don't know which permission in my manifest activates this.

I use following permissions in my manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ANDROID:It has added a new permission that needs to be added for jelly bean. Please read this article for more details:

http://www.androidguys.com/2012/06/29/jelly-bean-has-new-permission-option-to-read-external-storage/

There is a new developer option to turn on read access restriction, for developers to test their applications against how Android will behave in the future. So, when you hop into the development options on your Jelly Bean device, don’t be surprised to see this new option. We won’t see the permission in Android 4.1.0, but most likely in 4.1.1, and its intention is to keep your device more secure.

Currently this permission is not enforced and is used for testing on devices that have enabled Protect USB storage under Developer options in the Settings app on a device running Android 4.1 or higher.

Comment: Thank you. Thats what I needed to know, since my customer needed an explanation for the permissions.

Comment: Nice :) By the way your profile ask "Any Suggestions?" Where we can suggest ? :) :D @SubhalaxmiNayak